# Use timestamp field from json logs

Tags: logging, aws-fargate, grafana-loki

We have application which is in running in ECS fargate and logs are ingested to Grafana using Fluentd via the side car container. Application generates the log in json format and we have a timestamp in the log itself that I want to use. How do I configure Loki or Fluent Bit to use the timestamp from the log itself?

Logs are like below
2024-01-17 13:53:28.080 {"date":"2024-01-17T02:53:28.0588716Z"
however if we see Grafana timestamp has .080 at the end, but it should be .058, so basically there is delay in milliseconds, however this delay becomes greater when huge number of logs are generated.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the below line in config file of Fluentd,we were able solve the issue

```
   <parse>
        @type json
        time_key date
        time_format %iso8601
        keep_time_key true
    </parse>
```